# Nonlinear partial differential equation with boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm sorry for the bad texting,

I want to solve this partial differential equation but i can't due to wrong encoding i think.
If is solvable can someone write me the right code?

this is the equation:

D[D[f[x,t],x],x] + D[D[f[x,y],y],y] - (1/x)*D[f[x,y],x] +(x^2)*f[x,y] + f[x,y]^3 - a*f[x,y]=0

f[x,0]=1
f[0,y]=1
f'[x,0]=0
f'[0,y]=0

do i need more boundary conditions??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a non-linear Poisson Eqn modified by an advection term in the $x$ dimension and I think you meant to use a $y$ and not a $t$ in the first term. If so, then your equation is

$$
 \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}
+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}
 - \frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
 + x^2f+f^3-af=0
$$

where $f=f(x,y)$

You have all the boundary conditions that you need. I doubt (you could check Carslaw and Jaeger to be sure) that there is a closed form solution and the best approach would be to use finite differences with under-relaxation. Also, look up the Peaceman-Rachford ADI agorithm.

I would pay special attention to the advection term which becomes unbounded at $x=0$

Comment: The Peaceman-Rachford ADI is really for transient problems and frankly it may not be a bad idea to introduce a pseudo-transient term so that you can use the ADI and time-march to a steady state.

Comment: Try this:

$$
\frac{f_{i+1,j}+f_{i-1,j}}{\Delta x^2}
-\frac{1}{x_{i,j}}\frac{f_{i+1,j}-f_{i-1,j}}{2\Delta x}
-[a+2(\frac{1}{\Delta x^2}+\frac{1}{\Delta y^2})]f_{i,j}

=\frac{f^*_{i,j+1}+f^*_{i,j-1}}{\Delta y^2}-(x_{i,j})^2 f^*_{i,j}-(f^*_{i,j})^3
$$

which is a tri-diagonal system in the x direction (index $i$) for each $j$. The superscript * refers to values at a previous iteration.

After a tri-diagonal sweep, switch to the other direction (w/o the advection term) and repeat until convergence. You may need to resort to heavy under-relaxation. 

It helps if $a$ is large!!